# Add a page number from excel to word, VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have the following code that someone kind enough helped me to obtain:

```
'sidnummer
Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="PAGE  ", PreserveFormatting:=True
```

The only problem is that it comes an error which says :

"Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

How can I solve this?

Comment: Where are you running this? In Excel or Word? And what is selected when you run it?

Comment: Hey Andy. I am running this in Excel. Nothing is selected. I just want to add page numbers in the word document when I run my macro. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, _ 
    Text:="PAGE  ", PreserveFormatting:=True
```

As you are running this from Excel then the first `Selection` refers to whatever is currently selected *in Excel*. If you want to add a new `Field` to a Word document then you first need a reference to the Word application, and then to its `ActiveDocument`.

So then you might have:

```
yourWordAppRef.ActiveDocument.Fields.Add ..
```

The `Selection.Range` would also need to be modified so that it refers to a Word-Range - it currently refers to an Excel Range.

You also need a reference (in Excel) to the Word Object Library, otherwise Excel won't recognise the term `wdFieldEmpty`.

Comment: Is it any possibility that you can modify the code I posted into what you just wrote since I have some difficulties implementing it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: No, I won't do that - that's your job (and I don't have enough information to do it anyway).